# multiply two array values in php

Tags: php, arrays

I am trying to multiply two array values with each other with the following formula: `Qty* Price = total` of each multiple, then sum of all.

```
Array
(
[qty] => Array
    (
        [0] => .6
        [1] => .2
        [2] => .4
        [3] => .75
        [4] => 0.3
    )

[price] => Array
    (
        [0] => 1.2
        [1] => 0.5
        [2] => 0.8
        [3] => 12
        [4] => 2
    )

)
```

I could not figure out how to do that. Saw few example regarding the multiply in which they fixed value i.e. 2 or 5 etc. But in my case each qty has different price. Please can somebody suggest how to do that.

Comment: What do you have so far?

Comment: From the wording of the question I am not 100% sure what you mean. Do you have an array of prices and an array of quantities. Or is the key the quantity and the value the price? Also please post some code explaining how you get your variables.

Comment: are the arrays of equal lengths?

Comment: I'd like this question to be reopened. I edited it to make it more clear, with an example of the expected result and some boundaries that allow for a specific answer. I found myself with the very same problem and looking for an elegant way to solve it, and since there have been already more than 2,000 views, I think it would be worth a reopening. What do you think @jeroen?

Comment: @clami219 This question was closed as it does not show any effort and apart from that it was answered as far as the OP is concerned. If you have another question, you should ask a new one, not make big changes to this question.

Answer (score 4):

The following will work as long as both arrays are the same size.

```
for($i = 0; $i < count($qty); $i++) {
    $result[] = $qty[$i] * $price[$i];
}
```

The result will be in the `$result` array.

To get the sum:

```
echo "sum(result) = " . array_sum($result) . "\n";
```

Comment: Thanks njk for your reply, this is very helpful!