# Multiplying elements in an php array

Tags: php, arrays, for-loop

I have a really simple question but for some reason the output is not what I want.
I have 2 arrays:

```
total_hours = array(10, 20, 30);
hourly_rate = array(15, 10, 15);
```

So what I want to work out is how to multiple the corresponding element of `total_hours` with the `hourly_rate` (e.g. element 1: 10*15 = 150) then put this into an array called `total_sum` (total_sum has been initialized) . This is what I've done so far:

```
$total_sum = 0;
for($i=0; $i < sizeof($hourly_rate); $i++) {
    for($a=0; $a < sizeof($total_hours); $a++) {
        $total_sum = ($hourly_rate[$i]*$total_hours[$a]); 
    } 
    $total_pay[] = $total_sum;    
}
```

At the moment I get 0 and don't understand why.

Many thanks!

Comment: Please clarify your question. Your code says total sum is an integer not an array. Also, what's this about 0? Your result seems to be an array.

Comment: My apologies, ignore the total sum. Also I get 0 when I do a print statement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following is based on [this answer by Aarolama Bluenk](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14270531/19679), and should work as long as both arrays are the same size:

```
for($i = 0; $i < count($total_hours); $i++) {
    $result[] = $total_hours[$i] * $hourly_rate[$i];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use array_map with anonymous function to multiply hours with rates. array_map iterates over given arrays and returns result as array. Look http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php for more info.

```
$total_hours = array(10, 20, 30);
$hourly_rate = array(15, 10, 15);    

$total_pay = array_map(function($hour, $rate) {
    return $hour * $rate;
}, $total_hours, $hourly_rate);
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't want to have two loops, just one:

```
$total_pay = array();
for($i=0; $i < count($hourly_rate); $i++) {
  $total_pay[] = $hourly_rate[$i]*$total_hours[$i]; 
}
```

To get the sum of your final array, use `array_sum`.

Comment: I've tried your suggestion but now for some reason it iterates 3 times and I have no idea why, don't suppose you have any idea?

Comment: It iterates three times because your array only has three elements in it.  You wanted to multiply two arrays (each with three elements) together, so you only want to loop three times to make that happen.

Answer (score 0):

```
$total_hours = array(10, 20, 30);
$hourly_rate = array(15, 10, 15);

$mi = new MultipleIterator();
$mi->attachIterator(new ArrayIterator($total_hours));
$mi->attachIterator(new ArrayIterator($hourly_rate));

$total_pay = array();
foreach($mi as $details) {
    $total_pay[] = $details[0] * $details[1];
}
```