# How to calculate two arrays value

Tags: php, arrays

I have two arrays One with quantity and one array with price i want to multiply both of the array and finds its sum

Here are the two arrays

Quantity Array

```
Array
(
    [0] => 100
    [1] => 200
    [2] => 300
    [3] => 600
)
```

Price Array

```
Array
(
    [0] => 100
    [1] => 200
    [2] => 150
    [3] => 300
)
```

I want to get another array which will give me total if above two array like this

```
Array
(
    [0] => 10000
    [1] => 40000
    [2] => 45000
    [3] => 180000
)
```

Above is the multiple of above two arrays

Till now here is what I've tried

```
    $quantity =  $_POST['quantity']; 
    $price =  $_POST['price']; 
    $total_price = array();
    foreach ($price as $key=>$price) {
    $total_price[] = $price * $quantity[$key];
    }
```

But above method gives me error

Comment: You can manually do it or using a function.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [multiply two array values in php](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14270502/multiply-two-array-values-in-php)

Comment: What error do you see?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18432326/multiplying-two-arrays-in-php

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$quantity = $_POST['quantity']; 
$price = $_POST['price']; 
$total_price = array();

// assumption: $quantity and $price has same number of elements
// get total elements' count in variable. don't call count function everytime in loop.
$len = count($quantity);
for ($i=0; $i<$len; $i++) {
    $total_price[] = $price[$i] * $quantity[$i];
}

// var_dump($total_price) will give you desired output.
```

Answer (score 3):

Change the foreach statement, Using the main array name in the value is producing the error

```
foreach ($price as $key=>$price) {
```

Modify the above loop to :-

```
foreach ($price as $key=>$priceVal) {
  $total_price[] = $priceVal * $quantity[$key];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this change:

```
$total_price[$key] = $price[$key] * $quantity[$key];
```

Comment: What has changed?

Answer (score 0):

Iterate through the arrays and multiply their elements individually saving the result in a third array?

```
results = array();
for($c = 0; $c < count($quantity); $c++) {
  $results[$c] = $price[$c] * $quantity[$c];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$quantity =  $_POST['quantity']; 
$price =  $_POST['price']; 
$total_price = array();
$combine = array_combine($price,$quantity);

foreach ($combine as $price=>$quantity) {
    $total_price[] = $price * $quantity;
}
```

Comment: An explanation of what you have done and why this works would be helpful

Comment: use array_combine () ; for combine Price and Quantity in single array . in this array price vale as key and Quantity value as value . after that multiple this value and collect in $total_price

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php 
    $quantity = $_POST['quantity']; 
    $price = $_POST['price']; 
    $total_price = array(); 
    for ($i=0; $i<count($quantity); $i++) {
        $total_price[$i] = $price[$i] * $quantity[$i];
    }
?>
```

Please try this.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this,

```
$total_price = array_map("calculateTotal", $quantity, $price);
//print_r($total_price);

echo "Overall Price = " . array_sum($total_price);
function calculateTotal ($price, $qualitity) {
    return $price * $qualitity;
}
```